# Why is there no Tree<T> class in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures

The base class library in .NET has some excellent data structures for collections (List, Queue, Stack, Dictionary), but oddly enough it does not contain any data structures for binary trees. This is a terribly useful structure for certain algorithms, such as those that take advantage of different traversal paths. I'm looking for a correctly written, free implementation.

Am I simply blind, and not finding it... is it buried somewhere in the BCL? If not, can someone recommend a free or open-source C#/.NET library for binary trees? Preferably one that employs generics.

**EDIT:** To clarify what I'm looking for. I'm not interested in ordered dictionary collections that internally use a tree. I'm actually interested in a binary tree - one that exposes its structure so that you can do things like extract subtrees, or perform post-fix traversal on the nodes. Ideally such a class could be extended to provide the behaviors of specialized trees (ie. Red/Black, AVL, Balanced, etc).

Comment: Agreed.  I occasionally have the need to find (in O(Log N) time) the two nodes which bound a value (when the value is not found in the collection).  For example the collection (tree) contains 13 and 17 (among others) and I am looking for the greatest less than and least greater than 16.  A tree could do this, but Dictionaries, sorted lists, and hash tables take O(N).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You're right, there's nothing in the BCL. I suspect this is because the choice of whether to use a tree is typically an implementation detail and is otherwise an unconventional way to access data. That is, you don't say, "binary-search-for element #37"; instead, you say, "get me element #37".

But have you taken a look at [C5](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/Release1.1/c5doc/frames.htm)? It's super-handy and they have several tree implementations ([1](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/Release1.1/c5doc/types/C5.TreeBag_1.htm), [2](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/Release1.1/c5doc/types/C5.TreeDictionary_2.htm), [3](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/Release1.1/c5doc/types/C5.TreeSet_1.htm)).

Comment: C5 supports Red Black trees not B-Tree. They are differences whick people should be aware of. B-Tree is more optimal for a disk based tree or large memory based tree. More nodes are kept in the same locality so you get better processor cache performance and is quicker to read write to disk.

Answer (score 79):

You could define your own:

```
public class MyTree<K, V> : Dictionary<K, MyTree<K, V>>
{
    public V Value { get; set; }
}
```

Or unkeyed:

```
public class MyTree<V> : HashSet<MyTree<V>>
{
    public V Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This however requires you to know how many tree levels you will handle at compile time, am I wrong ?

Comment: No, the C# compiler supports this syntax.

Comment: Beware that elements are un-ordered this way

Comment: @Veverke Perhaps you were thinking of C++ templates. .NET generics are runtime types.

Comment: Im curious. How do you use this? Practically? Any sample?

Comment: To make it an ordered tree inherit from System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary

Answer (score 45):

What would you want from such an implementation?

Binary tree?
Red-black?
Radix tree?
B-tree?
R-tree?
R*-tree?

A tree is more a pattern than a data structure, and they tend to be used where performance matters (so implementation details probably matter too). If the BCL included some kind of a tree class, you'd only have to roll your own anyway

Comment: Best answer for the "why" part of the question.

Comment: And those are only the search trees. There are also expression trees, decision tress, ...

Comment: Indeed, the implementation details matter. In my case, I'm looking to implement some algorithms that would perform different traversals (infix, postfix) on an organized set of data as part of a series of transformations. A tree structure is the most elegant way of solving my problem.

Comment: In a parallel universe someone is asking the question: "Why are there no list types in .Net?", and they get the answer: "What would you want from such an implementation? An array? A linked list? A queue? A dictionary?" I think this is a non sequitur answer.

Answer (score 16):

I believe that `SortedDictionary` as the log(n) insert, retrieval characteristics that you would expect from a Tree Data Stucture.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 13):

[`SortedSet<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070(v=vs.110).aspx) is implemented as a binary search tree<sup>[ref](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/d0dc5fc099946adc1035b34a8b1f6042eddb0c75/src/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/SortedSet.cs#L19)</sup>. [`SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) internally makes use of `SortedSet<T>` so it too is a binary search tree <sup>[ref](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/SortedDictionary.cs#L954)</sup>.

Comment: Unfortunately these are simply implementations of ordered maps and lists. Neither is helpful for reuse as a binary tree - these tree structures are simply an implementation detail of the collection. I'm actually looking for a class that exposes the tree structure.

Answer (score 10):

No, there isn't any "`Tree<T>`-like" type in the BCL (something that has always puzzled me as well) but [here is a good article](http://dvanderboom.wordpress.com/2008/03/15/treet-implementing-a-non-binary-tree-in-c/) that will walk you through implementing your own in C#.

I guess you could make the argument that tree-based data structures are less commonly used in the kind of applications that .NET is usually used for (business apps, data-moving apps, etc.).  Still, I agree with you, it is strange that the BCL has no implementation at all.

Answer (score 0):

This series of articles was helpful for me when I had to write my own especially part 3 and 4.

[An Extensive Examination of Data Structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287104(VS.71).aspx)

Answer (score -5):

There's a [TreeNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.aspx) you can use.  It's not generic and hidden away in windows forms and used with the treeview control, but you can use it elsewhere as well.

Comment: Yeah, but it just has a Tag property of System.Object ype. No Generic <T> parameter

Comment: I always feel weird about doing stuff like that.  It's less visible with your specific example, but if people routinely re-purpose classes from, say, dependencies, this can result in hard-to-explain dependencies and can get you into trouble if the re-purposed class changes in an unexpected way across dependency versions.

Comment: What would be the profit of using it? A tree node does usually not have any relevant functionality in it. It just holds references to childs and eventually a parent. No reason to misuse a System.Windows.Forms class for it! Just write it yourself - in a minute or less.