# What .NET framework collection class is for modeling trees?

Tags: c#, data-structures, collections, tree

I have a sentence diagramming problem.  So I have a datastructure where a sentence holds sometimes a sentence, a subject, the subject holds sometimes another subject, which holds words, etc. So the nodes can hold instances of the same type as themselves and can hold a variety of kinds of nodes, but necessarily eventually hold a leaf object.

Right now I'm using custom classes and it looks like a muddle.

Is there a built in collection for trees, in the same way that there is a built in Array, Collection, Dictionary, List and Set?

Comment: this could be interesting for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942053/why-is-there-no-treet-class-in-net. Take a look at [C5](https://github.com/sestoft/C5/) collections.

Comment: For anyone who finds this Q, it is a duplicate of the one Jehof noted in the comment, not the other one noted in the close notification.